# How to use imagemagick in a Latex script?

Tags: pdftex, conversion

Trying to use ImageMagick in a LaTeX script. I can convert any pdf file to PNG image using ImageMagic.  This is what I came up with.

```
convert -density 300 -quality 90 input.pdf output.png
```

Is there any way to embed the above code `convert -density 300 -quality 90 input.pdf output.png` in LaTeX script to convert pdf to an image?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what your use case is? If you want to convert a pdf file to png then you can use the command you describe in the terminal/command prompt. If you want to include a pdf as a figure in your LaTeX document then you can just use \includegraphics{input}` for a file `input.pdf` without converting anything. If you want to convert many files and you are thinking of using LaTeX as a scripting language then this is possible but not really a good idea because other scripting languages are much more suited for such a task. So what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: In general, including an image as `pdf` is superior to including it as `png`, as the pdf may contain scalable graphics which will allow for arbitrary resolution (e.g. when zooming in), whereas png files have a fixed resolution (and may become big if you chose a fine resolution).